# Headers based routing with Slim 3

Tags: php, rest, http, routes, slim

I have a Slim 3 route: `$app->get('/calendar/{date}', 'CalendarCtrl:getSchedule');`
This route can return the same schedule by simple HTML list, json or xml format.
Now I'm looking for a simple REST solution based on `Accept` (or more headers) HTTP header.

For example:
Request:

```
GET /calendar/2017-01-01  
Accept: application/json
```

Response:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Body: {json schedule}
```

So a route should be smth like this: `$app->get('/calendar/{date}', {Accept: application/json}, 'CalendarCtrl:getScheduleJson');`

I know I can check for that header in a route handler. But I'm looking for a simple **declarative** solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a middleware to check for that header before sending the response from your API

```
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
//Checking for $req content-type here then send the response with the same one 
//example 
$headerValue= $req->getHeader('Accept');
if($headerValue=='application/json')
{
  $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
            ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
 }
else{

//check for other header here  
}      
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the middleware idea. It's a new concept for me, can you please advise me what best practices using middlewares are in Slim? You used an anonymous function, Slim docs use invokable class, other guides extend SlimMiddleware (Slim 2). What do you use as a best practice in middlewares? Thanks

Comment: One more question: in a case of Accept:text/html header I need to build an html page with Twig template rendering. It's a little but more complicated than simple `return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');` The question is: should such piece of logic be in a middleware? Maybe the controller is the right place? If it is, I go back to the previous question: middlewares don't solve the problem with headers based routing. It's not a routing at all.

Comment: Middleware in Slim is vary simple, You will provide a layer around your API Checking somethings before passing the request to the API and add somethings in the response before sending it to the client

Comment: In Slim3 adding middle ware is vary easy like my code here ,I use the add function to create any middelware layer